# Expo eas build ios fails at "Run fastline"

Tags: ios, react-native, expo, eas

I'm trying to build an Expo react-native app, in android the build succeed but in iOS is failing! It's failing in Run fastline task!
I did npx expo prebuild -c; After that I did eas build --platform ios; The only thing I changed after prebuild is at Podfile:

```
platform :ios, '13'
```

Because it showed me error when I tried to build, it showed `some pods require higher minimum deployment target`

Logs from EAS:

```
› Compiling Pods/Pods-DigiCache » Pods-DigiCache-dummy.m

› Packaging Pods/Pods-DigiCache » libPods-DigiCache.a

    Run script build phase 'Start Packager' will be run during every build because it does not specify any outputs. To address this warning, either add output dependencies to the script phase, or configure it to run in every build by unchecking "Based on dependency analysis" in the script phase. (in target 'DigiCache' from project 'DigiCache')

    Run script build phase 'Bundle React Native code and images' will be run during every build because it does not specify any outputs. To address this warning, either add output dependencies to the script phase, or configure it to run in every build by unchecking "Based on dependency analysis" in the script phase. (in target 'DigiCache' from project 'DigiCache')

› Executing DigiCache » [CP] Check Pods Manifest.lock

› Executing DigiCache » Start Packager on http://localhost:8081

› Copying   ios/DigiCache/Supporting/Expo.plist ➜ ./Expo.plist

› Compiling DigiCache » SplashScreen.storyboard


❌  (ios/Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-DigiCache/ExpoModulesProvider.swift:9:8)

   7 | 
   8 | import ExpoModulesCore
>  9 | import ExpoAdapterGoogleSignIn
     |        ^ compiling for iOS 12.4, but module 'ExpoAdapterGoogleSignIn' has a minimum deployment target of iOS 13.0: /Users/expo/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/DigiCache-axahioyuepmdwlciofskhedyjxrl/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/DigiCache/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/ExpoAdapterGoogleSignIn/ExpoAdapterGoogleSignIn.swiftmodule/arm64-apple-ios.swiftmodule
  10 | import EASClient
  11 | import ExpoImagePicker
  12 | import ExpoKeepAwake

› Compiling DigiCache » noop-file.swift


❌  (ios/Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-DigiCache/ExpoModulesProvider.swift:9:8)

   7 | 
   8 | import ExpoModulesCore
>  9 | import ExpoAdapterGoogleSignIn
     |        ^ compiling for iOS 12.4, but module 'ExpoAdapterGoogleSignIn' has a minimum deployment target of iOS 13.0: /Users/expo/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/DigiCache-axahioyuepmdwlciofskhedyjxrl/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/DigiCache/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/ExpoAdapterGoogleSignIn/ExpoAdapterGoogleSignIn.swiftmodule/arm64-apple-ios.swiftmodule
  10 | import EASClient
  11 | import ExpoImagePicker
  12 | import ExpoKeepAwake

› Preparing DigiCache » Info.plist

› Compiling DigiCache » ExpoModulesProvider.swift


❌  (ios/Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-DigiCache/ExpoModulesProvider.swift:9:8)

   7 | 
   8 | import ExpoModulesCore
>  9 | import ExpoAdapterGoogleSignIn
     |        ^ compiling for iOS 12.4, but module 'ExpoAdapterGoogleSignIn' has a minimum deployment target of iOS 13.0: /Users/expo/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/DigiCache-axahioyuepmdwlciofskhedyjxrl/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/DigiCache/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/ExpoAdapterGoogleSignIn/ExpoAdapterGoogleSignIn.swiftmodule/arm64-apple-ios.swiftmodule
  10 | import EASClient
  11 | import ExpoImagePicker
  12 | import ExpoKeepAwake

    Run script build phase '[CP-User] Generate app.config for prebuilt Constants.manifest' will be run during every build because it does not specify any outputs. To address this warning, either add output dependencies to the script phase, or configure it to run in every build by unchecking "Based on dependency analysis" in the script phase. (in target 'EXConstants' from project 'Pods')

    Run script build phase '[CP-User] Generate app.manifest for expo-updates' will be run during every build because it does not specify any outputs. To address this warning, either add output dependencies to the script phase, or configure it to run in every build by unchecking "Based on dependency analysis" in the script phase. (in target 'EXUpdates' from project 'Pods')

▸ ** ARCHIVE FAILED **

▸ The following build commands failed:

▸   SwiftEmitModule normal arm64 Emitting\ module\ for\ DigiCache (in target 'DigiCache' from project 'DigiCache')

▸   CompileSwift normal arm64 /Users/expo/workingdir/build/ios/DigiCache/noop-file.swift (in target 'DigiCache' from project 'DigiCache')

▸   SwiftCompile normal arm64 Compiling\ ExpoModulesProvider.swift /Users/expo/workingdir/build/ios/Pods/Target\ Support\ Files/Pods-DigiCache/ExpoModulesProvider.swift (in target 'DigiCache' from project 'DigiCache')

▸   CompileSwift normal arm64 /Users/expo/workingdir/build/ios/Pods/Target\ Support\ Files/Pods-DigiCache/ExpoModulesProvider.swift (in target 'DigiCache' from project 'DigiCache')

▸ (4 failures)

** ARCHIVE FAILED **

The following build commands failed:

    SwiftEmitModule normal arm64 Emitting\ module\ for\ DigiCache (in target 'DigiCache' from project 'DigiCache')

    CompileSwift normal arm64 /Users/expo/workingdir/build/ios/DigiCache/noop-file.swift (in target 'DigiCache' from project 'DigiCache')

    SwiftCompile normal arm64 Compiling\ ExpoModulesProvider.swift /Users/expo/workingdir/build/ios/Pods/Target\ Support\ Files/Pods-DigiCache/ExpoModulesProvider.swift (in target 'DigiCache' from project 'DigiCache')

    CompileSwift normal arm64 /Users/expo/workingdir/build/ios/Pods/Target\ Support\ Files/Pods-DigiCache/ExpoModulesProvider.swift (in target 'DigiCache' from project 'DigiCache')

(4 failures)

Exit status: 65

+-------------+-------------------------+

|           Build environment           |

+-------------+-------------------------+

| xcode_path  | /Applications/Xcode.app |

| gym_version | 2.210.0                 |

| sdk         | iPhoneOS16.0.sdk        |

+-------------+-------------------------+

Looks like fastlane ran into a build/archive error with your project

It's hard to tell what's causing the error, so we wrote some guides on how

to troubleshoot build and signing issues: https://docs.fastlane.tools/codesigning/getting-started/

Before submitting an issue on GitHub, please follow the guide above and make

sure your project is set up correctly.

fastlane uses `xcodebuild` commands to generate your binary, you can see the

the full commands printed out in yellow in the above log.

Make sure to inspect the output above, as usually you'll find more error information there

[stderr] [!] Error building the application - see the log above

Error: Fastlane build failed with unknown error. See logs for the "Run fastlane" and "Xcode Logs" phases for more information.
Fastlane errors in most cases are not printed at the end of the output, so you may not find any useful information in the last lines of output when looking for an error message.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you also need to update this in your xcode project. if you use `npx expo prebuild` to generate your ios project, you can set this with [expo-build-properties](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/build-properties/#pluginconfigtypeios).

[image: "general" -> minimum deployments on ios]

Comment: Yes, I added the config plugin expo-build-properties and it worked :D thank you :D